# Android NDK: build fat binary with BUILD_EXECUTABLE and armeabi-v7a-hard

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-build

**Short:** How does Android NDK system transform "APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a-hard" to final .so files located in "libs/armeabi-v7a"? What is the proper way to do same thing in Android.mk? Currently, to build standalone executable and place it in folders corresponding to different ABIs I use this, which is it looks ugly because of hard coded "ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a-hard)":

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
SAVED_NDK_APP_DST_DIR := $(NDK_APP_DST_DIR)

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a-hard)
    NDK_APP_DST_DIR := assets/armeabi-v7a
else
    NDK_APP_DST_DIR := assets/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
endif

LOCAL_MODULE := run_pie
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := run_pie.c    
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
NDK_APP_DST_DIR := $(SAVED_NDK_APP_DST_DIR)
```

**Long:** In my Android app I'm using set of standalone binaries. After build they stored in APK resources. On first app launch I copy them to my app private folder, chmod 777, and than use them as system utilities, like "ls" or "cp". I want to produce "fat binary": single APK that has binaries for all ABIs and choose right binary for current device after installation. For .so libraries Android doing all this stuff automatically. And "APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a-hard" is internal to NDK build system, it's stated in docs, and final .so files for "armeabi-v7a-hard" is placed in "armeabi-v7a" folder. I can do same for my binaries and currently I have way that is working, however it looks ugly.

**What is the proper way to place output binaries to custom folders named with ABIs and handle "armeabi-v7a-hard" to "armeabi-v7a" conversion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into `$NDK/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk`, you'll find the following lines there:

```
# compute NDK_APP_DST_DIR as the destination directory for the generated files
NDK_APP_DST_DIR := $(NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT)/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
# install armeabi-v7a-hard to lib/armeabi-v7a, unless under testing where env. var. _NDK_TESTING_ALL_
# is set to one of yes, all, all32, or all64
ifeq (,$(filter yes all all32 all64,$(_NDK_TESTING_ALL_)))
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a-hard)
NDK_APP_DST_DIR := $(NDK_APP_LIBS_OUT)/armeabi-v7a
endif
endif
```

So, as you see, it's the same approach as you do in your `Android.mk`. The only difference is that you don't take into account `_NDK_TESTING_ALL_`, which is internal to NDK testing system. So just continue use your `Android.mk` as is and don't worry.

Another approach would be to build your executables as usual, but name them as `lib${TOOLNAME}.so`. In this case they will be placed into default `NDK_APP_DST_DIR` as well as real libraries, and when installing on device, Android Package Manager will copy them into proper place. Then, on first run, you could copy them from `lib` folder (rather than from assets, as you do currently), and rename appropriately.

Comment: Many thanks, that exactly what I was looking for. I tried to find that place in NDK sources, but `setup-toolchain.mk` is escaped my attention. Currently I also looking propher way to find ABI at runtime. I know about `Build.CPU_ABI`, `Build.CPU_ABI2` and `System.getProperty("os.arch")`, however I want to find how it's handled in the sources of Android package installer, almost found at this moment. But your option with `lib${TOOLNAME}.so` is interesting too, thank again.